# No device specified for hibernation [Arch Linux]

Tags: linux, arch-linux, grub2, hibernate

on startup showing

```
ERROR : no device specified for hibernation
```

here are my related files
`/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="5"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Arch"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=UUID=49fdf0fb-49bb-4d3d-afa0-388fdca1a07d loglevel=3 quiet "
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Preload both GPT and MBR modules so that they are not missed
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="part_gpt part_msdos"

# Uncomment to enable booting from LUKS encrypted devices
#GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK="y"

# Set to 'countdown' or 'hidden' to change timeout behavior,
# press ESC key to display menu.
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"

# Uncomment to use basic console
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="console"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal
#GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE="auto"

# Uncomment to allow the kernel use the same resolution used by grub
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="keep"

# Uncomment if you want GRUB to pass to the Linux kernel the old parameter
# format "root=/dev/xxx" instead of "root=/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxx"
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment and set to the desired menu colors.  Used by normal and wallpaper
# modes only.  Entries specified as foreground/background.
#GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="light-blue/black"
#GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="light-cyan/blue"

# Uncomment one of them for the gfx desired, a image background or a gfxtheme
#GRUB_BACKGROUND="/path/to/wallpaper"
#GRUB_THEME="/path/to/gfxtheme"

# Uncomment to get a beep at GRUB start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

# Uncomment to make GRUB remember the last selection. This requires
# setting 'GRUB_DEFAULT=saved' above.
#GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"

# Uncomment to disable submenus in boot menu
#GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU="y"

# Probing for other operating systems is disabled for security reasons. Read
# documentation on GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER, if still want to enable this
# functionality install os-prober and uncomment to detect and include other
# operating systems.
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="false"
```

`/etc/fstab`

```
# See fstab(5) for details.

# <file system> <dir> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
# /dev/nvme0n1p6
UUID=45a70118-0949-454e-9eae-1ff09723a1df   /           ext4        rw,relatime 0 1

# /dev/nvme0n1p5 LABEL=endeavour\134x20home
UUID=251e761e-d7a7-41cc-98b2-3e395298d7f4   /home       ext4        rw,relatime 0 2

# /dev/nvme0n1p8
UUID=3BD9-31EA          /boot       vfat        rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro   0 2

# /dev/nvme0n1p7
UUID=49fdf0fb-49bb-4d3d-afa0-388fdca1a07d swap           swap    defaults   0 0
```

`/proc/cmdline`
`BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux-zen root=UUID=45a70118-0949-454e-9eae-1ff09723a1df rw loglevel=3 quiet`

Comment: Did you do manual changes without running `update-grub`? Is the swap partionion actually existing (check via e.g. `swaplabel`).